Characterizing sets of measure zero of the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra.
I have a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ defined on the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ which satisfies the property that $\mathbb{P}(\{n\}) > 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Define a cylinder in the usual way as:
$$ C_t[a] = \{(n_1, \ldots, n_{t-1}, a, n_{t+1}, \ldots ) : \forall i: n_i \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
with $a \in \mathbb{N}$. A cylinder set is the intersection of finitely many cylinders. Denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all cylinders by $\mathcal{C}$.
Is it true that a set $A \in \mathcal{C}$ has measure zero, i.e. $\mathbb{P}^{\mathbb{N}}(A) = 0$, if and only if $A$ is the intersection of infinitely many cylinders or a countable union of such sets? If not, are there any characterizations of the null-sets of this $\sigma$-algebra?

The answer to your first question is no. For example, the union of two sets of measure $0$ also has measure $0$ but is not likely to be an intersection of
cylinders.
I doubt that there is a simple characterization of sets of measure $0$ that isn't essentially a restatement of "a set of measure $0$".  In probabilistic language, you have a sequence of iid $\mathbb N$-valued random variables $X_n$ with $\mathbb P(X_n = j) > 0$ for all $j \in \mathbb N$, and you want to know what events have probability $0$.
[EDIT]
The Kolmogorov $0-1$ law states that any event that is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{X_n : n > N\}$ for every $N$ has probability either $0$ or $1$.  Such events are typically not countable unions of intersections of cylinders.  For example, the Strong Law of Large Numbers says that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N X_n = \mathbb E[X_i]$ with probability $1$.

You are of course correct regarding the first question. I have edited the question to exclude the case where we consider the union of a finite intersection of cylinders.
